# How to access a singleton from other classes C++

Tags: c++, class, singleton

I can't find any answer to this question for C++ (for other languages yes) though I've searched for a number of hours.  How can I access a Singleton from another class?

Declaration:

```
#include "Store.h"
Store *store = Store::Instance();      // Singleton

int main()
{
  store->GetDepts();
  return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to access it from my Customer Proxy class:

```
#include "Store.h"
class Cust_Proxy
{
public:
  Cust_Proxy(string cust_name)
  {
    name_ = cust_name;
  }
  void AddItem(Item item)
  {
    store->AddItemToShoppingCart(item);    // or something, just for example
  }
private:
  string name_;
  ShopCart cart_;
};
```

I've tried passing it as a parameter but obviously there's no public constructor in the singleton "store":

```
void AddItem(Store *store) 
{ 
  store = Store::Instance();
  // Do Stuff; 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
store->AddItemToShoppingCart(item);
```

use

```
Store::instance()->AddItemToShoppingCart(item);
```

You don't need to store the pointer to the singleton in `main.cpp` or any other function that uses the singleton. Access the singleton by calling `Store::instance()` whenever you need it.

In `main`, you can use:

```
int main()
{
  Store::instance()->GetDepts();
  return 0;
}
```

and remove the line

```
Store *store = Store::Instance();      // Singleton
```

Comment: That seems logical but I get an error saying that "'Store' is not a class or namespace name", even though I can access all functions within the store from within main(). E.g., the function call within main() works (in above code)

Comment: @bertmoog, I can't tell why you are seeing such an error without seeing the contents of Store.h.

Comment: @R Sahu Thank you for your help... store header and cpp is posted

Comment: Moved implementation into separate .cpp and it seems to recognize "Store" now.